# Construir un objeto con un parámetro LocalDate (Java)

Tags: java, string, formato, constructor, localdate

Necesito definir un constructor de una clase en Java en la que uno de los Atributos es la fecha de nacimiento definida con `LocalDate`, pero en el constructor debe estar definida como `String`.
Es decir

Atributo de la clase es: `private LocalDate fecha_nacimiento`, y en el constructor debe construirse así:

```
public persona (...,String fecha_nac)
```

E instancias un objeto la fecha debe pasarse en formato `dd/mm/yyyy` como `String`

, he intentado formatearla y demás peros siempre me da error. Alguna sugerencia o ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

no tengo mucho tiempo ahora mismo, por lo que no puedo explicarte el código, pero creo que esto puede servirte:

```
    package exercises;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Exercise4 {

    /* Atributos */
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatEurope = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/LL/yyyy");
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatAmerican = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/LL/dd");


    private Exercise4() {

    }

    public static String normalToAmericano(String date) {

        LocalDate lDate;

        try {
            lDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatEurope);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fecha en formato no válido.");
        }

        return lDate.format(formatAmerican);

    }

    public static String americanoToNormal(String date) {

        LocalDate lDate;

        try {
            lDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatAmerican);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fecha en formato no válido.");
        }

        return lDate.format(formatEurope);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Fecha en formato original: 30/01/1990. Fecha en formato americano: %s%n", 
                Exercise4.normalToAmericano("30/01/1990"));

        System.out.printf("Fecha en formato americano: 1990/01/30. Fecha en formato normal: %s",
                Exercise4.americanoToNormal("1990/01/30"));
    }

}
```

Es un ejercicio que hicimos en clases recientemente. Fíjate en LocalDate.parse(string, formato). Con eso podrás hacer lo que necesitas.